# YouTube Reporting API Report Download Error

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, youtube-analytics-api

I am receiving an error message when trying to download YouTube Reporting API bulk reports on behalf of a content owner.

I have successfully created report jobs and report job returns download URLs but the download fails with the following error message:

A service error occurred: Invalid json in service response:

> date,channel_id,video_id,claimed_status,uploader_type,country_code,ad_type,estimated_youtube_ad_revenue,ad_impressions,estimated_cpm

Please can someone help me understand what this error means and how to resolve the issue?  I've tracked issue down to failure in function downloadReport.  The line that fails is:

```
response = $client->execute($request);
```

I have used the PHP sample code provided on Google developers here: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/#code-samples

My version of code for "Retrieve a report" follows:

```
<?php

/**
 * This sample retrieves reports created by a specific job by:
 *
 * 1. Listing the jobs using the "jobs.list" method.
 * 2. Retrieving reports using the "reports.list" method.
 *
 * @author Ibrahim Ulukaya
 */

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once '/../src/Google/autoload.php';
require_once '/../src/Google/Client.php';
require_once '/../src/Google/Service/YouTubeReporting.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);

/*
 * This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
 * authenticated user's account.
 */
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-content-owner-readonly');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// YouTube Reporting object used to make YouTube Reporting API requests.
$youtubeReporting = new Google_Service_YoutubeReporting($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    if (empty(listReportingJobs($youtubeReporting, $htmlBody))) 
    {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>No jobs found.</p>');
    } 
    else
    {
        if ($_GET['reportUrl'])
        {
            downloadReport($youtubeReporting, $_GET['reportUrl'], $htmlBody);
        }
        else
        {
            if ($_GET['jobId'])
            {
               retrieveReports($youtubeReporting, $_GET['jobId'], $htmlBody);
            }
        }
    }
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}


/**
 * Returns a list of reporting jobs. (jobs.listJobs)
 *
 * @param Google_Service_YouTubereporting $youtubeReporting YouTube Reporting service object.
 * @param $htmlBody - html body.
 */
function listReportingJobs(Google_Service_YouTubeReporting $youtubeReporting, &$htmlBody) {
  // Call the YouTube Reporting API's jobs.list method to retrieve reporting jobs.
  $optParams=array("onBehalfOfContentOwner"=>"REPLACE_ME");

  $reportingJobs = $youtubeReporting->jobs->listJobs($optParams);

  $htmlBody .= "<h3>Reporting Jobs</h3><ul>";
  foreach ($reportingJobs as $job) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>id: "%s", name: "%s" report type: "%s"</li>', $job['id'],
        $job['name'], $job['reportTypeId']);
  }
  $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  return $reportingJobs;
}

/**
 * Lists reports created by a specific job. (reports.listJobsReports)
 *
 * @param Google_Service_YouTubereporting $youtubeReporting YouTube Reporting service object.
 * @param string $jobId The ID of the job.
 * @param $htmlBody - html body.
 */
function retrieveReports(Google_Service_YouTubeReporting $youtubeReporting, $jobId, &$htmlBody) {
  // Call the YouTube Reporting API's reports.list method to retrieve reports created by a job.
  $optParams=array("onBehalfOfContentOwner"=>"REPLACE_ME");
  $reports = $youtubeReporting->jobs_reports->listJobsReports($jobId, $optParams);

  if (empty($reports)) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>No reports found.</p>');
  } else {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<h2>Reports for the job "%s"</h2>', $jobId);
    foreach ($reports as $report) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<ul><li>From "%s" to "%s" downloadable at "%s"</li>',
          $report['startTime'], $report['endTime'], $report['downloadUrl']);
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  }
}


/**
 * Download the report specified by the URL. (media.download)
 *
 * @param Google_Service_YouTubereporting $youtubeReporting YouTube Reporting service object.
 * @param string $reportUrl The URL of the report to be downloaded.
 * @param $htmlBody - html body.
 */
function downloadReport(Google_Service_YouTubeReporting $youtubeReporting, $reportUrl, &$htmlBody) {
  $client = $youtubeReporting->getClient();
  // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
  // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
  $client->setDefer(true);

  // Call the YouTube Reporting API's media.download method to download a report.
  $request = $youtubeReporting->media->download("");
  $request->setUrl($reportUrl);
  $response = $client->execute($request);

  file_put_contents("reportFile", $response->getResponseBody());

  $client->setDefer(false);
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Retrieve reports</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="GET">
    <div>
      Job Id: <input type="text" id="jobId" name="jobId" placeholder="Enter Job Id">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      Report URL: <input type="text" id="reportUrl" name="reportUrl" placeholder="Enter Report Url">
    </div>
    <br>    <input type="submit" value="Retrieve!">
  </form>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt its related but did you double check the content owner id?  maybe contact the YouTube content partners manager and make sure it was setup.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I can confirm that the correct content owner ID has been passed.

Comment: Update: Only header rows output as day I used had no data.  JSON error still occurs when there is data and weirdly the error message is actually the expected output data in full!

I know it is in full as the Java version of the same script seems to work fine and comparison of Java output vs PHP error shows that data match but as it's an error it stops code before outputting data to file in PHP script.

This PHP error seems to be within the Google Service itself and have tracked it down to API script "/Google/http/REST.php"  Has anyone else experienced the same error and has a fix?